# Invalid Request body in retrofit while enabling the Progaurd

Tags: android, retrofit2, proguard

When I am adding the progaurd file in the release build, keep getting the error "Invalid Request Body". Upon Checking I found out,  Request body passing as {}, why this is behaving as?

Proguard-rules.pro file

```
-keep class com.android.vending.billing.**

#event bus
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe <methods>;
}
-keep enum org.greenrobot.eventbus.ThreadMode { *; }

# And if you use AsyncExecutor:
-keepclassmembers class * extends org.greenrobot.eventbus.util.ThrowableFailureEvent {
    <init>(java.lang.Throwable);
}

#timber
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** v(...);
    public static *** e(...);
}

 
#google play billing
-keep class com.android.vending.billing.**

#no need to add the progaurd rule for rx-java 2- https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/6243

#for youtube player
# Needed to keep generic types and @Key annotations accessed via reflection
-keepattributes Signature,RuntimeVisibleAnnotations,AnnotationDefault
# Needed by google-http-client-android when linking against an older platform version
-dontwarn com.google.api.client.extensions.android.**
# Needed by google-api-client-android when linking against an older platform version
-dontwarn com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.**
# Needed by google-play-services when linking against an older platform version
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
# com.google.client.util.IOUtils references java.nio.file.Files when on Java 7+
-dontnote java.nio.file.Files, java.nio.file.Path
# Suppress notes on LicensingServices
-dontnote **.ILicensingService
# Suppress warnings on sun.misc.Unsafe
-dontnote sun.misc.Unsafe
-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe

-dontwarn com.google.common.**
-dontwarn com.google.api.client.json.**

#event bus
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe <methods>;
}
-keep enum org.greenrobot.eventbus.ThreadMode { *; }

# And if you use AsyncExecutor:
-keepclassmembers class * extends org.greenrobot.eventbus.util.ThrowableFailureEvent {
    <init>(java.lang.Throwable);
}

#pinview no need

#retrofit

# Retrofit does reflection on generic parameters. InnerClasses is required to use Signature and
# EnclosingMethod is required to use InnerClasses.
-keepattributes Signature, InnerClasses, EnclosingMethod

# Retrofit does reflection on method and parameter annotations.
-keepattributes RuntimeVisibleAnnotations, RuntimeVisibleParameterAnnotations

# Retain service method parameters when optimizing.
-keepclassmembers,allowshrinking,allowobfuscation interface * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}

# Ignore annotation used for build tooling.
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement

# Ignore JSR 305 annotations for embedding nullability information.
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**

# Guarded by a NoClassDefFoundError try/catch and only used when on the classpath.
-dontwarn kotlin.Unit

# Top-level functions that can only be used by Kotlin.
#-dontwarn retrofit2.KotlinExtensions
#-dontwarn retrofit2.KotlinExtensions$*

# With R8 full mode, it sees no subtypes of Retrofit interfaces since they are created with a Proxy
# and replaces all potential values with null. Explicitly keeping the interfaces prevents this.
-if interface * { @retrofit2.http.* <methods>; }
-keep,allowobfuscation interface <1>

#keep your models
-keep class packagename.parent.models.** { *; }
-keep class packagename.child.models.** { *; }
-keep class packagename.rest.service.** { *; }
-keep class packagename.rest.service.responce.** { *; }
-keep class packagename.child.service.statics.model.** { *; }


#okhttps3
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-keep class okhttp3.* { *;}
-dontwarn okio.

#glide
-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep class * extends com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule {
 <init>(...);
}
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.ImageHeaderParser$** {
  **[] $VALUES;
  public *;
}
-keep class com.bumptech.glide.load.data.ParcelFileDescriptorRewinder$InternalRewinder {
  *** rewind();
}
# Uncomment for DexGuard only
#-keepresourcexmlelements manifest/application/meta-data@value=GlideModule

#room
-keep class * extends androidx.room.RoomDatabase
-dontwarn androidx.room.paging.**

#timber
-dontwarn org.jetbrains.annotations.**

#crashlytices
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception
```

Why I am getting "Invalid request body" error? Why the request body is not created? Why pro-guard not taking model class into account?

Answer (score 1):

Annotate your each data model class with **@Keep** annotation then it will not shrink your data classes references.
You can also read the documentation here https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/annotation/Keep

Answer (score 0):

## Retrofit

```
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions
-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

```
-keepattributes RuntimeVisibleAnnotations
-keepattributes RuntimeInvisibleAnnotations
-keepattributes RuntimeVisibleParameterAnnotations
-keepattributes RuntimeInvisibleParameterAnnotations

-keepattributes EnclosingMethod

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit2.* <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers interface * {
    @retrofit2.* <methods>;
}
```